# HTTP IP camera not working on Pi but working on Ubuntu

Tags: camera, opencv, rtsp

I have a situation, I have two IP cameras one on RTSP and other on HTTP, I am using Python 3.4.2 and OpenCV 3.4.1 on my Raspberry Pi, I am able to read from My webcam and RTSP IP camera, but when I try to read from HTTP IP camera it returns no frames. I tried the same code on Ubuntu, it works well on Ubuntu.

What could the problem be?

```
vs = VideoStream(src="http://192.168.75.203/video/mjpg.cgi").start()
while True:
    frame = vs.read()
```

Comment: Is this problem resolved. Can you post your complete code.?

Comment: What error does it gives you